# Getting { expectedcss(css-lcurlyexpected) Error in CSS file

Tags: html, css, syntax-error

The colons in the CSS below for padding, box-sizing and font-family have a red line under them and give the following error (this is the one for padding):

> Selector Specificity: (0, 0, 1) {
> expectedcss(css-lcurlyexpected) Peek Problem (⌥F8) No quick fixes
> available

my css code:

```
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
```

I have no idea what i have done wrong. Any advice please?

Comment: Is it in vs code??